# Windows 8 - Photo app tile - Can't set picture for tile

Tags: windows-8, photos, file-format, tiles

Prior to the windows 8.1 update I was able to choose any given photo from my pictures library and set it as the tile to appear on my start screen.  However, as soon as I updated my laptop, the photo I had set disappeared and when I tried to change it back the following message came up ...

"Can't change the Photos tile to this photo - the file may be damaged or in an unsupported format."

This happens each time, no matter which photo I select.  As far as I am aware, my photos are still the exact file they were before hand, I have tried saving copies in numerous formats such as JPEG and PNG yet it still seems to come up with the same message.  My photos have not moved folder and I have not edited them in any way since before I updated to windows 8.1.

Please help me and thank you for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to windows explorer and change the folder options to view thumbnails.  View-> options-> view-> uncheck box that says Always show icons, never thumbnails